# Bootstrap 3 Table with Inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a datagrid interface with Bootstrap 3 which would look like this:

[image: The desired datagrid]

Any suggestion how I will obtain this result?

**With table or div's, or there is no way and I will have to write custom CSS for the table and the inputs?**

Note that my datagrid usually has a lot of columns.

Comment: Use a tool like Bootply and try some different options: http://www.bootply.com/117707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all these months, and after using twitter bootstrap in several projects, I noticed  that bootstrap.css is a 'compiled' tool.

And any other compiled tool, it must not be manually changed, unless you do it directly to the source code, and in this case, is the **.less** code.

So to solve the problem I listed in my question above, I basically ran into a solution like this one http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial, this link describes the proccess in more details.

I hope that this conclusion can help the other people looking at this thread.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem which I solved with the [editable-table bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/gr2m/bootstrap-editable-table).
Hope it helps.